# AJAX and Python Error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, jquery

I'm building a Javascript library that can talk to a simple Python web server using AJAX.

Here is the web server class:

```
class WebHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def parse_POST(self):
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
        if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
            postvars = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
        elif ctype == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            length = int(self.headers['content-length'])
            postvars = urllib.parse.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length),
                                             keep_blank_values=1)
        else:
            postvars = {}
        return postvars

    def do_POST(self):
        postvars = self.parse_POST()

        print(postvars)

        # reply with JSON
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.end_headers()
        json_response = json.dumps({'test': 42})
        self.wfile.write(bytes(json_response, "utf-8"))
```

And here is the Javascript method I'm using:

```
var send_action = function() {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.51:8000";
    var post_data = {'gorilla': 'man'};

    $.post(url, post_data, function(data) {
        alert("success");

    })
      .done(function(data) {
        alert("second success");

    })
      .fail(function() {
        alert("error");

    })
      .always(function() {
        alert("finished");
    });
};
```

When I run the server and call the JS function the server prints `{'gorilla': 'man'}` but then the browser flashes the *error* alert followed by the *finished* alert. In the developer log I have:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.51:8000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The same thing happens when I specify *dataType*s in `$.post` like so:

```
$.post(url, post_data, function(data) {
    alert( "success" );
}, 'json')
```

or

```
$.post(url, post_data, function(data) {
    alert( "success" );
}, 'jsonp')
```

Both the server and the browser session are on the same machine.

## Solution

Needed to add extra headers after `self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")`:

```
self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
self.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: What should I import to be able to inherit from "http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a lot of topics about: Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Add this lines after: `self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")`

```
self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
self.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
self.send_header(("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: You have a few typos but this worked, thank you so much!